# Check if any word in string is in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gigantic list (800 items) and one really long string. I want to get the first item in the array that matches the part of the string and stored in a variable.

My code currently:

```
for (var i = 0; i<gigantic_genre_array.length; i++) {
  var test_genre = thelongstr.indexOf(gigantic_genre_array[i]);
  if(test_genre != -1) {
    tag1 = gigantic_genre_array[test_genre];
    alert(tag1);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work like I thought it would, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<gigantic_genre_array.length; i++){
          var test_genre = thelongstr.indexOf(gigantic_genre_array[i]);
          if(test_genre!=-1){
            tag1 = gigantic_genre_array[i];
            alert(tag1);
          }
        }
```

Comment: what did you change in the original code.? I cannot see anything.?  ....  oops I had seen that. you jus replaced the index with `i`..!

Comment: he changed `gigantic_genre_array[test_genre]` to `gigantic_genre_array[i]`

Comment: `tag1 = gigantic_genre_array[i];` instead of `tag1 = gigantic_genre_array[test_genre];`

Answer (score 0):

Do the process reversely it will be efficient too.

```
var wordArray = thelongstr.split(' ');

for(var i=0,len = wordArray.length; i < len; i++)
{
  if(gigantic_genre_array.indexOf(wordArray[i]) > -1)
   {
     alert(wordArray[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a RegExp based on the array and test it against the string:

```
var gigantic_genre_array=['foo','bar','foobar'];
var thelongstr='where is the next bar';

alert(new RegExp(gigantic_genre_array.join('|')).exec(thelongstr)||[null][0]);
//returns bar
```